# Need to get passport for US citizen child; other parent will not cooperate by providing ID

Tags: usa, passports

Is there anything I can do to get my kid's passport? I have the signed and notarizes papers from her father, saying that I could take her out of the country, but he would not provide a copy of his ID.

Comment: If you have the identification required by the US State Department to get a passport, you should be good to go.  You will not need her father's identification.  You may need a notarized letter of permission, however, to take your daughter out of the country if you don't take her together.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie the instructions on [form DS-11 (pdf)](https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds11.pdf) do not agree with you.

Comment: At this point, you can either kill him, or go to court and have his custody rights revoked.

Comment: I have the notarized letter that has his Id number on it. They say they still need a copy front and back of his Id. He also has to go for 6 months no contact before I can get his custodial privileges revoked.

Answer (score 3):

From the application, DS-11:

>  AS DIRECTED BY PUBLIC LAW 106-113 AND 22 CFR 51.28:
>
> To submit an application for a child under age 16 both parents or the child's legal guardian(s) must appear and present the following:
>
> - Evidence of the child's U.S. citizenship;
> - Evidence of the child's relationship to parents/guardian(s); AND
> - Original parental/guardian government-issued identification AND a photocopy of the front and back side of presented identification.
>
> IF ONLY ONE PARENT APPEARS, YOU MUST ALSO SUBMIT ONE OF THE FOLLOWING:
>
> - Second parent's notarized written statement or DS-3053 (including the child's full name and date of birth) consenting to the passport issuance for the child.
>     The notarized statement cannot be more than three months old and must be signed and notarized on the same day, and must come with a photocopy of
>     the front and back side of the second parent's government-issued photo identification; OR
> - Second parent’s death certificate if second parent is deceased; OR
> - Primary evidence of sole authority to apply, such as a court order; OR
> - A written statement or DS-5525 (made under penalty of perjury) explaining in detail the second parent's unavailability.

So you have a couple of options, namely a court order or, more plausibly, DS-5525.  Unfortunately, I have no idea of the chance of success in either case.